# using binding to center a circle

Tags: javafx-8

Here is a program that attempt to center a circle using binding:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class Test extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        Circle c = new Circle();
        Group root = new Group(c);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 100, 100);
        c.centerXProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty().divide(2));
        c.centerYProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty().divide(2));
        c.radiusProperty().bind(Bindings.min(scene.widthProperty(),
                scene.heightProperty())
                .divide(2));
        c.radiusProperty().addListener((obs, old, nw) -> {
            System.out.println(" oldRadius = "+old + ", newRadius = "+nw );
        });
        stage.setTitle("Binding in JavaFX");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.sizeToScene();
        stage.show();

    }

}
```

**Here is the screen when the program is initially run:**

[image]

notice that the circumference of the circle touches only the top, left, and bottom sides not the right side.

**Here is the screen when the screen for the program is maximized and then restored:**
[image]

Here the circumference of the circle touches only the top and bottom sides.

1. the screens shown above are normal?
2. How do I explain this behavior for that program?

Comment: My guess would be for some reason the scene width and height aren't calculated correctly before it is put in a stage, but are not correctly triggering a change event when put inside a stage. Could very well be wrong though, it's just a guess.

Comment: I just copied your code and tested it with JDK 1.8.0_60 on Ubuntu 14.04 - it seems to work like you intended it to, without the described phenomenon. Which JDK did you use?

Comment: @RobertRohm I'm using JDK 1.8.0_60 on windows vista.

Comment: Maybe it would be best to file a bug.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the faulty behaviour on Windows 7 JDK 1.8.0_66.